# Get file content from multiple web pages using Dom Xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

When I execute this code only 2nd iteration's details are showed.
How can I iterate through both pages page 1 and page 2?

I have following code div which resides img:

```
  $ratings = array();       
for ($pageNum = 1; $pageNum < 3; $pageNum++) {

    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/store/abc/page/$pageNum");            
    @$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

    //Init the XPath object
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    //Query the DOM
    $rating = $xpath->query( '//div[contains(@class, "rating fl")]//img' );

    //Display the results as in the previous example

    foreach ($rating as $link) {
        //echo  $link->getAttribute('title'),'<br>';            
        $ratings[] = $link->getAttribute('title');                    
        if (sizeof($ratings) == 15) {
            //  var_dump($ratings);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reset `$ratings` on every iteration so you only have the last passes values in the `$ratings` array.

Simplified version:

```
for($pageNum=1; $pageNum<3;$pageNum++){
    $ratings = array();
    $rating = array(0,1,2);
    foreach($rating as $link){
        $ratings[]  = $pageNum;
        echo $pageNum;
     }
}
print_r($ratings);
```

Output:

```
111222Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
)
```

If you comment out the ratings intializing or move it outside the loop it should work as expected.

```
for($pageNum=1; $pageNum<3;$pageNum++){
    //$ratings = array();
    $rating = array(0,1,2);
    foreach($rating as $link){
        $ratings[]  = $pageNum;
        echo $pageNum;
     }
}
print_r($ratings);
```

Output:

```
111222Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 2
)
```

Comment: Can you modify the above code ,because after I put array ratings declarations outside the loop it only iterate through first page.

Comment: Or should I use 2 d array

Comment: Can you update your question to show your updated code?

Comment: If I can put $ratings[0][0] = $link->getAttribute('title'); and make a way to column number in $ ratings array change dynamically as page number, I think I can archive expected result. I'm trying to do that but bit logic

Comment: The placement of `$ratings` is correct and the array is populated correctly using that code. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6dd5c8ff4386b9b4c79595e82626d2044a9a10a Check if `$rating` is populated everytime.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `$ratings[0][0]`. `$ratings` isn't multidimensional, is it?

Comment: It shows page number 1 , 2 times not go to second page

Comment: thanks chris85 There was logical errors in html page. Thanks again for your time